# Facebook share button with diverse links

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like, href

I am trying to use the regular Facebook share button, but instead of giving it a specific link. I wan't the link to be diverse, by this I mean, I wan't the link to change depending on a certain function of which happens inside of a php script. 
The only issue is the fact, that I can't seem to make it work. 
Underneath here I have attached my code, along with a short break down of what I have done so far.

- First off I have a div with the id "passToJ", inside this div I have a php code of which gets a post value and then uses "echo" to write and show it on my page. This part is working, as the exact value, which needs to be showed, is showed.
- Second part is a javascript of which gets the value inside the "passToJ" div. After that it then adds that value to a link, to make a larger link, with an added variable. It then takes this link and implements in the Facebook href link, of which is necessary. This is a little complicated, but it is a bunch of numbers, which according to the Facebook docs page needs to be there and then inside I have added my own real link by the javascript.
- The Javascript then adds those links(href and data-href) to the actual Facebook button of which is written below the javascript function. This is where I guess the issue is. In the "data-href" field it has to include the "complLink" variable value and in the regular "href" it has to include the "complLinkDos".

The value is showing on the page, so far so good. But the actual function of getting the link values to the Facebook, isn't working.

An important note, might be the fact that when trying to use the "share" button. It does work, it just isn't using the right link, it is just using the link of the actual page it is on. Which it isn't supposed to.

```
<div id="passToJ">
<?php
    $linkAffId = $_POST['hiddenAffIDH'];
    echo htmlspecialchars($linkAffId);
?>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            var div = document.getElementById("passToJ");
            var linkToSha = div.textContent;
            var complLink = "https://example.com/" + linkToSha;
            var complLinkDos = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%example.com"+"%2F"+linkToSha+"&amp;src=sdkpreparse";

            document.getElementById("fbSBut").data-href=complLink; 
            document.getElementById("fbLinking").href=complLinkDos; 
</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" id="fbSBut" data-href="" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" id="fbLinking" target="_blank" href="">Share</a></div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("fbSBut").data-href=complLink` - you can not access attributes that contain a - like that; right now what you have written here is a _subtraction_ ...

Comment: But why JavaScript in the first place? You might as well create the correct URL with PHP, and then output it as the value of the data-href attribute of the share button. No idea why you think this needs a detour via JavaScript at all.

Comment: @CBroe I am terribly sorry for getting back to you so late, I see what you mean, but how exactly would I go about doing that? I know how to create the right url inside the PHP and have it passed to the new page, but how would I then add it as "data-href" attribute to the Facebook button?

Comment: `data-href="<?php echo $someshit; ?>"`

Comment: @CBroe Alright I see, thank you very much for the heads up and help.